# SQL Query not completing correctly - not sure why

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Alright, 
I've got a multiple select dropdown on a page called week-select, its selections get passed via ajax to my php page.

I can get the data just fine, but when the query runs it doesn't complete appropriately.

I've got this:

```
    //Deal with Week Array
    $weekFilter = $_GET['week']; /*This is fine, if it's 1 week the query works great (weeks are numbered 12-15), but if it is 2 weeks the result is formatted like this 12-13 or 13-14-15 or whichever weeks are selected*/
    $weekFilter = str_replace("-",",",$weekFilter); /*This works to make it a comma separated list*/

    .../*I deal with other variables here, they work fine*/

    if ($weekFilter) {
        $sql[] = " WK IN ( ? ) ";
        $sqlarr[] = $weekFilter;
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
    if (!empty($sql)) {
        $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $sql);
    }   
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($sqlarr);
    $finalarray = array();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $finalarray['count'] = $count;
    if ($count > 0) { //Check to make sure there are results 
    while ($result = $stmt->fetchAll()) { //If there are results - go through each one and add it to the json
            $finalarray['rowdata'] = $result;
        } //end While
    }else if ($count == 0) { //if there are no results - set the json object to null
            $emptyResult = array();
            $emptyResult = "null";
            $finalarray['rowdata'] = $emptyResult;
    } //end if no results
```

If I just select one week it works great and displays the appropriate data.

If I select multiple options (say weeks 12, 14 and 15) it runs the query but only displays week 12.

When I manually input the query in SQL, how I imagine this query is getting entered - it runs and displays the appropriate data.  So if I put SELECT * FROM mytablename WHERE WK IN ( 12, 14, 15 ) it gets exactly what I want.

I can't figure out why my query isn't executing properly here.
Any ideas?

**EDIT: I make the array from the multiple selections a string using javascript on the front end before it is passed to the backend.

Comment: why don't u simply echo the query when u do multipe select, than u see the problem in a sec ...

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I create a prepared statement for IN () operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991146)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resulting query with values probably looks like this with a single value in `IN`:

```
…  WK IN ("12,14,15") …
```

Either use one placeholder for each atomic value:

```
if ($weekFilter) {
    $values = explode(",", $weekFilter);
    $sql[] = " WK IN ( " . implode(",", array_fill(0, count($values), "?")) . " ) ";
    $sqlarr = array_merge($sqlarr, $values);
}
```

Or use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of IN:

```
$sql[] = " FIND_IN_SET(WK, ?) ";
```

Comment: I think you're on the right path here - the IN is probably looking at a single value.  Trying to make your example code work (it doesn't work for me as is and I'm still learning).  Currently it gives me this error: "syntax error, unexpected ';' in"  on the $sql[]= line.  

This has me going in a good direction though.

Comment: @Hanny There was just a `)` missing.

Comment: Still getting an error: "array_fill() expects exactly 3 parameters, 2 given in ..."  
But getting there :) Still digging - I think you've got me on the right path.  Seeing if I can make it work.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth - I make the array a string on the front end using javascript before it's passed to the PHP on the backend.

Comment: @Hanny Ok, fixed that too.

Comment: Excellent.  It works now - you're the man Gumbo, thanks for your help.  This gives me some great insight into how to dissect this stuff too.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bind an array to a singular `?` placeholder. Usually you have to put in as many `?` values as there are elements in your array.

Answer (score -1):

If your HTML is correct and your week select has `name="week[]"`, then you will get an array back with `$_GET['week'];`, otherwise without the `[]` it will only give you 1 value. Then, you're doing a string replace, but it's not a string.  Instead, try this:

```
$weekFilter = implode(',', $_GET['week']);
```